# Mono IPv4 versus IPv6 issues: SocketException: Invalid arguments

Tags: c#, sockets, ubuntu, mono, ipv6

I have a Mono .NET application that uses [ppatierno.AzureSBLite](https://github.com/ppatierno/azuresblite) to receive data from an Azure ServiceBus.

The code is straightforward:

```
var factory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
var client = factory.CreateEventHubClient(eventHubEntity);
var group = client.GetDefaultConsumerGroup();
var receiver = group.CreateReceiver(partitionId, startingDateTimeUtc);
EventData = receiver.Receive();
```

On my VM running 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04, using Ubuntu's Mono packages, it works flawlessly.

On my build server running Ubuntu 14.04, in a 64-bit 16.04 chroot (so the chroot environment should have all of the same userland packages as the VM), using Ubuntu's Mono packages, I get the following error:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Invalid arguments
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginMConnect (System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncResult sockares) <0x41029e20 + 0x001df> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnect (System.Net.IPAddress[] addresses, Int32 port, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state) <0x41029720 + 0x00107> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnect (System.String host, Int32 port, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state) <0x41027720 + 0x0008f> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Amqp.TcpTransport+<>c__DisplayClass3.<ConnectAsync>b__0 (System.AsyncCallback c, System.Object s) <0x41027670 + 0x00073> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncImpl (System.Func`3 beginMethod, System.Func`2 endFunction, System.Action`1 endAction, System.Object state, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions) <0x7fc54c2c8700 + 0x001cf> 24334 in <filename unknown>:0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x7fc54c0016d0 + 0x00029> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x7fc54bfff6b0 + 0x000a7> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x7fc54bfff630 + 0x0006b> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x7fc54bfff5e0 + 0x0003a> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () <0x7fc54bfff5c0 + 0x00012> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Amqp.TcpTransport.Connect (Amqp.Connection connection, Amqp.Address address, Boolean noVerification) <0x410219b0 + 0x0015e> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Amqp.Connection.Connect (Amqp.Sasl.SaslProfile saslProfile, Amqp.Framing.Open open) <0x41021680 + 0x0006b> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Amqp.Connection..ctor (Amqp.Address address, Amqp.Sasl.SaslProfile saslProfile, Amqp.Framing.Open open, Amqp.OnOpened onOpened) <0x4101ba40 + 0x00227> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Amqp.Connection..ctor (Amqp.Address address) <0x4101b9b0 + 0x0001b> in <filename unknown>:0
  at ppatierno.AzureSBLite.Messaging.Amqp.AmqpMessagingFactory.Open (System.String entity) <0x4101b760 + 0x001b7> in <filename unknown>:0
  at ppatierno.AzureSBLite.Messaging.Amqp.AmqpMessageReceiver.ReceiveEventData () <0x4101afb0 + 0x00042> in <filename unknown>:0
  at ppatierno.AzureSBLite.Messaging.EventHubReceiver.Receive () <0x4101ab40 + 0x0001f> in <filename unknown>:0
  at ReceiveEdgeData.EdgeReceiver.MainLoop () <0x4101a920 + 0x0004b> in <filename unknown>:0
```

If I understand the strace output correctly, the non-functioning host is creating an IPv6 socket and trying to directly connect to an IPv4 address:

```
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(5671), sin_addr=inet_addr("52.176.47.198")}, 16) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
```

While the functioning host is using something like [dual-mode sockets](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/01/08/dual-mode-sockets-never-create-an-ipv4-socket-again/) to correctly represent the IPv4 address as an IPv6 address:

```
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(5671), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::ffff:52.176.47.198", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=htonl(0), sin6_scope_id=0}, 28) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
```

Given that this is happening somewhere inside Mono and its dependencies, how do I troubleshoot and fix this?

Comment: All the code involved is open source, that does help a bit (for example, [`Socket.cs`](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/Socket.cs)). The logical next thing to check is whether Mono is indeed to blame, or if it's getting fed bad data from the upper layer. Specifically, a breakpoint at `System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnect` would establish if the input arguments are the same on both machines. This does involve digging in on the machines themselves with a [debugger](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/debug+profile/debug/).

Comment: I suppose you have different mono version on those machines? As I remember Ubuntu 14 has mono 3.x and 16 has 4.x

Comment: @Evk - I'm running in a 16.04 [chroot environment](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot), so the Mono versions should be identical, although the host kernels differ.